# Replace full path with one string if

Tags: awk, sed

I have a lot of paths in one file and i need to change paths with specific string IF there is .jpg, .pdf
For example:
I have right now lines like those:

```
images/2015/somename.jpg
images/2012/somefile.pdf
```

2015/2012 could be 1997 or 2010 etc - random year numbers.
I would like to change those lines with sed (if possible)  like this

```
images/somename.jpg
files/somefile.pdf
```

I tried like so:
`echo "images/2015/image12345.jpg" | sed 's/images[^0-9]*[^0-9]/\/images/;'` - no result

Or maybe awk will be good tool for this job?

Comment: Why are you matching on non-numbers when your middle component contents are all numbers?

Comment: I just tried something to make it work. I'm not good with sed - sorry

Comment: You want to match and remove `/####` so match that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
images/2015/somename.c
images/123/somename.jpg
1234/2015/somename.jpg
images/2015/somename.jpg
images/2012/somefile.pdf

$ awk '/\.(jpg|pdf)$/ {sub("/[0-9]{4}/","/")} 1' file
images/2015/somename.c
images/123/somename.jpg
1234/somename.jpg
images/somename.jpg
images/somefile.pdf
```

Comment: Ed Morton, i got it now - thank you!
Now i have to adjust it to make it work as needed.

Answer (score 0):

With gnu-sed: `sed -r '/\.(jpg|pdf)$/s#/[0-9]+/#/#'`

`/\.(jpg|pdf)$/`: Matches lines ending with `.jpg` or `.pdf`

`/[0-9]+/`: Matches any sequence of just digits between slashes

Example:

```
$ echo "images/2015/image12345.jpg" | sed -r '/\.(jpg|pdf)$/s#/[0-9]+/#/#'
images/image12345.jpg
```